# Oracle JOIN in cursor only if a certain metadata is found for input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle18c

I have a cursor with a join like so:

```
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT *
        FROM table_1 a
             JOIN table_2 b
                                ON b.ID_1 = a.ID_1
       WHERE     TABLE_ID IS NOT NULL
             AND TABLE_ID = p_input_id;
```

I want to modify the cursor and add 3 more joins only if p_input_id IS found in a metadata table. So I want to do something like this:

```
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT *
        FROM table_1 a
             JOIN table_2 b
                                ON b.ID_1 = a.ID_1
             CASE 
                 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM METADATA_TABLE 
                              WHERE INPUT_ID = p_input_id 
                              AND FLAG = 'Y') 
                 THEN 
                     JOIN table_3 c
                                        ON c.ID_2 = b.ID_2
                     JOIN table_4 d
                                        ON d.ID_3 = c.ID_3
             END
       WHERE     TABLE_ID IS NOT NULL
             AND TABLE_ID = p_input_id;
```

How can I accomplish this? I could consider using LEFT JOIN instead of the case/join. Are there any issues with this?

```
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT *
        FROM table_1 a
             JOIN table_2 b
                                ON b.ID_1 = a.ID_1
             LEFT JOIN table_3 c
                                ON c.ID_2 = b.ID_2
             LEFT JOIN table_4 d
                                ON d.ID_3 = c.ID_3
       WHERE     TABLE_ID IS NOT NULL
             AND TABLE_ID = p_input_id;
```

I'm trying to avoid breaking the current cursor for the p_input_id's which are using it. There will be new p_input_id's which need to use the extra table joins.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Prepare the sql string based on the input value.

Comment: I added a few more updates. Please see, execute immediate is the only route?

Comment: It's still not clear what's your requirement. If you have proper relationship between the tables, then you just need to join all the tables including metadata table and put the input as filter.

Comment: You don't clearly say what you want--invalid code doesn't mean anything. So we can't tell you if your final code is correct. Why would or wouldn't it be? What is a clear specification? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values or say what rows you want in terms of what's in the tables. You seem to want some columns from some rows of a cross join of those tables--which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` for `table_3` and `table_4` and `count` in `metadata` table as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 A
    JOIN TABLE_2 B ON B.ID_1 = A.ID_1
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS CNT
             FROM METADATA_TABLE
            WHERE INPUT_ID = P_INPUT_ID
              AND FLAG = 'Y') MT
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 C ON C.ID_2 = B.ID_2
                           AND MT.CNT > 0
    JOIN TABLE_4 D ON D.ID_3 = C.ID_3
                      AND MT.CNT > 0
WHERE TABLE_ID IS NOT NULL
  AND TABLE_ID = P_INPUT_ID;
```

`COUNT` is used in the `metadata` table to ensure that it returns only one record.(replacement of `exists`)